# How to match a QRegExp in PyQt5 with contains

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I want to translate a C++ source to PyQt5 source. In there I have to translate the following statement:

```
key.contains(rx)
```

where key is a QString and rx a QRegEx.

Since PyQt5 we no longer have access to a QString and a python string of course does not support the contains method with a QRegExp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`QRegExp::indexIn`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qregexp.html#indexIn). So that translates into

```
rx.indexIn(key) != -1
```